# How to create a time duration in a for loop - (mismatched types int and time.Duration)

Tags: go

I have a loop where I start by a time.Time and I what to add a minute.

```
 for idx := range keys {
    var a = idx * time.Minute
    var t = tInit.Add(time.Minute * a)
    fmt.Println(t, idx)


 }
```

Here is my error

```
invalid operation: idx * time.Minute (mismatched types int and time.Duration)
```

Comment: The error tells you the problem--you have a type mismatch. You cannot multiply mismatched types together, so they must be converted to the same type.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The operands to numeric operations must have the same type. [Convert](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) the `int` value `idx` to a `time.Duration`: `var a = time.Duration(idx) * time.Minute`

Answer (score 2):

As a developer in other programing languages I found this the most counterintuitive and illogical way of doing it. I worked in Scala in the last 10 years, and it could be as simple as this:

`val a = idx minutes`

compared that, the Go way:

`var a = time.Duration(idx) * time.Minute`

is more verbose, but that wouldn't be the end of the world.

The problem is that multiplying a Duration with another Duration doesn't make any sense if what you want is to obtain another Duration as a result, because from a physical point of view that would be measured in something like seconds squared.

According to the documentation time.Minute is a constant:

```
const (
    Nanosecond  Duration = 1
    Microsecond          = 1000 * Nanosecond
    Millisecond          = 1000 * Microsecond
    Second               = 1000 * Millisecond
    Minute               = 60 * Second
    Hour                 = 60 * Minute
)
```

And all those are defined in terms of the Duration type which is an alias for int64:

```
type Duration int64
```

From what I see is perfectly fine to multiply an integer literal with each one of these constants, after all that's how each one is defined in relation to the others.

So, to recap why is `60 * time.Second` valid syntax (and makes perfect sense), but:

```
var secondsInAMinute := 60

var oneMinute = secondsInAMinute * time.Second
```

is invalid. This doesn't make any sense.

All those constants are of type Duration. That means they are measured in units of time (multiples of one nanosecond to be precise).

So, it seems the "correct" way to do it (correct in the sense that it compiles and works) doesn't make any physical sense. Let's look at this again:

`var a = time.Duration(idx) * time.Minute`

So, we are multiplying time.Duration(idx) with time.Minute.

The type for `time.Minute` is Duration which should be measured with a time unit. In physics it the accepted unit for time is the second. It seems Go uses integer nanoseconds instead, so time.Minute represents a Duration, represented internally in nanoseconds. That's fine.

The problem is that `time.Duration(idx)` also "converts" the integer idx to a Duration, so in physics it would also be represented as a unit of time, like seconds. So, accordingly, time.Duration(idx), in my opinion, represents `idx nanoseconds` in Go.

So, basically, when we write `time.Duration(idx) * time.Minute` we are muliplying `idx nanoseconds` (idx * 0.0000000001 seconds) with `one minute` (60 seconds).

So, from a physical point of view `time.Duration(idx) * time.Minute` would represent `idx * 0.000000001 seconds * 60 seconds`. Or, simplified, `idx * 0.00000006 seconds squared`.

Now, in what world is `idx * 0.00000006 seconds squared` equal to `idx * 1 minute`?

So, now I know, in Go, if you want to apply a multiplier to a duration, you have to multiply that Duration to another  Duration, and divide that in your mind with `one millisecond` so that all this mess can still makes any kind of physical sense.

I understand that all these unit inconsistencies are the result of the "The operands to numeric operations must have the same type." constraint. But that doesn't make it more logical or less annoying. In my opinion that restriction of the Go language should be removed.

But, for anyone that was lost in my explanations, let's see how illogical all this is with a concrete code example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    var oneMinute = 1 * time.Minute
    var oneNanosecond = 1 * time.Nanosecond

    var oneMinuteTimesOneNanoSecond = oneMinute * oneNanosecond
    
    fmt.Println(oneMinuteTimesOneNanoSecond)
}
```

The result is exactly what I expected from this nonsensical way of doing time calculations:

```
1m0s
```

I'll learn to live with this, but I will never like it.

Comment: Interesting insight. Logic/physics aside, it's just down to the way the compiler evaluates everything. When you have a single line expression like `60 * time.Second`, the compiler realises that `60` is a `time.Duration` and not an `int`, but when you assign it to a variable first, if you don't specify that it's type is `time.Duration` then it'll be assigned as an `int`, and hence the example that "doesn't make any sense" doesn't compile.